# How do I turn off typing suggestions in iOS 10?

Tags: ios

Several iOS 10 apps enable typing suggestions by default, even if these were disabled prior to iOS 10. This is especially notable in Messages, where the suggestions include emoji.

How do I disable typing suggestions in iOS 10?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Tap and hold the language key (the one that looks like a globe or possibly an Emoji smile face) and set the toggle for "Predictive" to off.

[image]

Comment: nice, But iOS 9 show\hide predictive text was much better. Just swipe up and down.

Comment: Nice is in the eye of the beholder, I suppose. I was constantly flicking it on and off accidentally.

Comment: I prefer the old way. Note: this solution doesn't work if you only keep one keyboard active in system settings (if you've disabled emoji).

Answer (score 4):

If, like mine you do not get the option to change the keyboard on your messages app. Go to Settings > General > Keyboard > Predictive.
Here you can switch it off.

Comment: This is such a confusing setting. I really believed it would entirely disable predictive text, but it was just the bar. Why doesn't it at least mention that? I prefer how iOS9 at least allowed you to drag the bar up and down

Answer (score 0):

The problem with this is that it also seems to shut off autocorrect and predictive text *within* the text bar -- I want nothing to do with the suggested words that can be tapped, but I like the autocorrect and suggestions that hover while typing. If that makes sense.

Update: Actually, this only seems to happen when turning off predictive text within the settings app. So this is good.

Comment: What exactly is your answer here? It's kind of hard to follow with the edit.